# ActiveAdmin, nested resources and default_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, activeadmin

I've got a simple app that has two models - a Show model and an Episode model -- of course a show can have many episodes, and I have them showing up in the active admin interface within the Show edit as nested resources quite nicely.

An episode has an 'approved' boolean which should keep it showing up on the front end; so I added a default_scope in the Episode model default_scope where(:approved => true) -- but this now makes any non-approved episode from showing up in the admin Show edit as well.

I'm trying to work with the Show register resource and change the scope for it's nested resources but that's not working at all; I try to change the Episode register resource in active admin as well but THAT's not showing up either…

Hopefully someone can understand what the issue is? If it was a case of one model having to change it to unstopped it'd be simpler, but I'm basically looking at ONE resource and trying to change the default scope of the NESTED resource of that resource...

Comment: This is actually what's spewing out: `code`  Show Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "shows".* FROM "shows" WHERE "shows"."slug" = 'the-first-show' ORDER BY "shows"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Episode Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "episodes".* FROM "episodes" WHERE "episodes"."approved" = 't' AND "episodes"."show_id" = ? ORDER BY episode ASC  [["show_id", 1]]
  Embed Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "embeds".* FROM "embeds"
`code`  -- I don't want the default scope of "episodes"."approved"='t'

Comment: Would you be able to share some of your ActiveAdmin resource definitions? It might help illustrate your question.